# Using contenteditable div for two way binding

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the contents from my model in a div which is contenteditable. User will modify this content and it should get saved in my model. I have used the example provided at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController.

The code is available at http://plnkr.co/edit/ruKtNfDWP17npbFU4Te9?p=info
`var app = angular.module('docApp', []);`

The issue is:

1. ng-model attribute does not output the data in the div as it does in the input control. Therefore I have to use binding expression.
2. Because of that editing goes beserk.

How do I get it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Please inline your code in your question. Links can go down any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience `contenteditable` is extremely tricky for angular to deal with. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/528#issuecomment-7573166) (which has been open for over 3 years) for a lengthy discussion. You may want to try some third party modules such as [akatov/angular-contenteditable](https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable).